# How to make thicker stem lines in matplolib

Tags: python, stem

I want to make thicker stem lines in python when using `plt.stem`.

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 20

n = np.arange(0, 2*N, 1)

x = np.exp(-n/N)*np.exp(1j * 2*np.pi/N*n)

plt.stem(n,x.real) 

plt.show()
```

I changed `plt.stem(n,x.real,linewidth=10)`, but nothing changed. Is there no function to set the `linewidth` in `plt.stem`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of [`plt.stem`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.stem) shows that the function returns all the line objects created by the plot. You can use that to manually make the lines thicker after plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 20
n = np.arange(0, 2*N, 1)
x = np.exp(-n/N)*np.exp(1j * 2*np.pi/N*n)

markers,stems,base = plt.stem(n,x.real) 
for stem in stems:
    stem.set_linewidth(10)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 8):

This can also be modified using `plt.setp()` as is shown in the matplotlib documentation [example](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.stem).  The [`plt.setp()` method](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.setp) allows you to set the properties of an artist object after it has been created.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.1, 2*np.pi, 10)
markerline, stemlines, baseline = plt.stem(x, np.cos(x), '-.')
plt.setp(stemlines, 'linewidth', 4)

plt.show()
```

[image]