# How to control stem markers size in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, markers, stem

In [How to make thicker stem lines in matplolib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292117/how-to-make-thicker-stem-lines-in-matplolib) there is a description of how to control the width of stem lines. But how to control the size of the stem markers?

Answer (score 11):

```
markerline, stemline, baseline, = ax.stem(x,y,linefmt='k-',markerfmt='ko',basefmt='k.')
plt.setp(stemline, linewidth = 1.25)
plt.setp(markerline, markersize = 5)
```

While the first two code lines are taken from the link in my question, the third code line changes the marker's size.

Comment: Is there no way to do this in the stem function itself, or set the sizes globally?